# Display date as red if it's longer than 2 years ago

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes **Community** (diamond) bumps questions which not have had an accepted answer to the top of the questions queue. However, some questions of these are over 2 or 3 years old.

Sometimes I'm close to putting a comment to an answer/a question and then see last second before posting it, the answer was about 2-3 years ago (and so was the question).
The comment is irrelevant at that point because example now; someone was explaining Windows XP in bootcamp, which isn't supported for a long time anymore (at least since OS X 10.6)

Could it be an option to display the date (on the bottom of a question and answer) in red if the date is 2 or more years old?

Comment: Why not just post or comment on the question? The site helps numerous people other than the asker.

Comment: A lot of users aren't logged in for a while, getting no details or answers back at all.

Comment: @Rob- the might be a case to vote to close as insufficient information

Answer (score 1):

Special markings for a really old date of a question might be somewhat helpful.

But it is not helpful for the examples given. This question is now over 3 years old and didn't receive an accepted answer. Yet the question is interesting enough for me at least to write this now.

No one should assume that there are only beta-freaks out there that throw away everything if the day after tomorrow there will be a new phone around in the shop.

The OP gave 10.6 and XP as examples of hopelessly obsolete configurations in 2014 and mixes this with the date of some questions he saw then.

Yet even today there are users out there that are still working with these machines and configurations.

*Any interesting question,* even if its findings might be not that transferable, because it is relating to strictly those old configurations, might very well serve others finding themselves in a similar situation. *If they get answers!*

Why should older configurations be excluded? There is retro-computing, content-as-is users, poorer people having to make do, even institutions or workflows dependent on a special configuration that others might laugh about otherwise.

Marking out really old questions is primarily useful as an indication that if one is about to answer this and primarily motivated by gaining reputation that this might be not that good of an 'investment'. Chances rise that the OP is not interested anymore in having an answer, may be she left the site already for good. Producing an accepted answer gets quite difficult under these circumstances. But if I understand the system correctly, any answer there could then still be upvoted.

Also, if the question is of suboptimal quality, requiring more details or entirely different info from the OP, somewhat interactive troubleshooting steps to encircle the problem, then this might of course get hard.

That means the OPs question might be expanded:

not only might the original question date be somewhat bigger or better to glance at, but also that it would be useful if some kind of two separate activity indicators were introduced:

- one for the question, comparing all those comment dates and history is time consuming
- one for the OP, indicating two things: very low activity on site for some time now, and: contact somehow lost

Therefore this might be a good idea for many but primarily for Rep-investors and Archeologists.

Although especially the latter type (not congruent with Badge-owners) might profit more from better, more sophisticated, or 'just more' filter mechanisms on the question pages.